# How to know once all the SNS subscribers received the message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed-computing, amazon-sns, distributed-system

Let's say I have set up a AWS SNS with 3 subscribers. I'd like to know when all of the subscribers received/processed the message in order to mark that message as processed by all 3, and to generate some metrics.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What if a receiver gets the message and crashes? You only care about the fact of receiving the message, or its successful processing by the consumer?

Comment: I mean successful processing by the consumer

Answer (score 2):

You can [log delivery status for SNS topics to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html), but only for certain types of messages (AWS has no reliable way of knowing if some messages were received or not, such as with SMS or email).

**The types of messages you can log are:**

- HTTP
- Lambda
- SQS
- Custom Application (must be configured to tell AWS that the message is received)

**To set up logging in SNS:**

1. In the SNS console, click "Edit Topic"
2. Expand "delivery status logging"
3. Then you can configure which protocols to log and the necessary permissions to do so.

Once you're logging to CloudWatch, you can draw metrics from there.

If you need to be notified when the subscribers have received the messages, you could set up a [subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) within cloudwatch to send the relevant log events to a lambda function, in which you would implement custom logic to notify you appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

> I mean successful processing by the consumer

Usually your consumers would have to indicate this somehow. This is **use-case specific**, therefore its difficult to speculate on exact solutions.

But just to **give an example**, a popular patter is [Request-response messaging pattern](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-temporary-queues.html#request-reply-messaging-pattern). In here, your your consumers would use a SQS queue to publish outcome of the message processing. The producer(s) would pull the queue to get these messages, subsequently, knowing which messages were correctly process and which not.